# Bounding Fourier coefficients in terms of supremum norm

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $\gamma_1,\dotsc,\gamma_n$ be nonnegative real numbers.
Let $\eta_1,\dotsc,\eta_n$ be real numbers.
Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by:

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i e^{2\pi i \cdot \eta_i x}\!.$$

Is there a function $G:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} $ such that

1. $G(t)\rightarrow  0$ as $t\rightarrow 0^+$
2. $\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i \leq G(\|f\|_\infty)$

I want $G$ not to depend on $n$.

In other words, I want to show that $\sum \gamma_i$ tends $0$ as $\|f\|_\infty$ tends of zero at a rate which depends only on the rate at which $\|f\|_\infty$ tends to zero, and not on $n$.

Comment: I doubt it, especially if you aren't choosing the $\eta_i$ according to any orthogonality condition.

Comment: @Ian: What do you mean by orthogonality condition? If I understand, I can think if it applies in my case.

Comment: @Ian: Actually, I can just say what "my case" is: $f$ comes from an arbitrary finite dimensional (unitary) complex representation of $\mathbb{R}$ by means of a diagonal matrix coefficient with respect to a unit vector.

Comment: Unless $e^{2 \pi i \cdot \eta_i x}$ are orthogonal, I see no good reason to be able to control $\sum_i \gamma_i$ by any norm of $f$. Even then I'm not so sure about controlling it by $L^\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f(0)=\sum_{i=1}^n\gamma_i\implies\sum_{i=1}^n\gamma_i\le\|f\|_\infty
$$
Thus $G(t)=t$ works. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you. You're not missing anything :) I posted a variant here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765499/variant-bounding-fourier-coefficients-in-terms-of-supremum-norm